# Improve SqlBulkCopy performance

Tags: c#, sql, sqlbulkcopy

I have a data table import from VFP and insert into Sql server.The table has 10000 rows and 190 columns. 
Now it takes about 4 seconds to insert into database.

Here is my Code:

```
using (var bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(connect, SqlBulkCopyOptions.UseInternalTransaction))
//Also try this, but no effect 
//using (var bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(connect, SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepIdentity)) 
{
    foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
    {
        bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(col.ColumnName, col.ColumnName);
    }

    //bulkCopy.BatchSize = 1000;
    //Also try this, but no effect 

    bulkCopy.BulkCopyTimeout = 600;
    bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = dt.TableName;
    Stopwatch sw6 = new Stopwatch();
    sw6.Start();
    bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dt);
    sw6.Stop();
    Logs.FileLog("Data Update Time: " + (sw6.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000).ToString());
}
```

Please Help.

Comment: how long do you feel it should take?  If all 190 columns have only an integer in it for 10,000 rows that is 7 MB of data which if you are running this on the same server as where VFP and sql sit that isn't too much but if on separate systems now you have network latency as well.  Add to that you likley have some varchar so lets say if your average column data length is 15 you are now looking at 27 mb.  plus you have the overhead to establish the connection.

Comment: Using TableLock usually, increase performance by obviously locking the table. You may get around 30% performance improvement and maybe more.

Comment: Thanks Matt, That make perfect sense. I was asked to reduce time in every way. And it seems that 4 seconds shouldn't be a big issue.

Comment: Thanks, Jonathan, but tablelock didn't make big difference here. with bulkcopy, I guess 4 seconds is finally what I have.